# How to translate the cloud pages based on the browser language in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, landing-page, cloudpage

I have been working in custom preference centre and one of the requirement is to translate the page based on the browser language. The difficulty here is detecting the browser language  "**Navigator.language"** returns the browser language however its a client side function. The translations are managed through AMP Script, how can we get this language value passed to AMP Script?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible:

1. With [GetUserLanguages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformHTTPPropertyGetUserLanguages.htm) SSJS function - but from initial testing this works only in Microsites, not on CloudPages
2. Getting [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header with [GetRequestHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformHTTPPropertyGetRequestHeader.htm) SSJS function - this will work for both Microsites and CloudPages
3. With [HTTPRequestHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httprequestheader.htm) Ampscript function - same header as above

You can pass values from SSJS to Ampscript with [SetValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAMPscriptVariableSetValue.htm)